# pgfkeyvalue string is not parsed by xkeyvalue

Tags: pgfkeys, xkeyval

I'm trying to create a database using pgfkeys. It is working rather well, until I needed to execute some parameters stored in a key and pass it to some command that uses xkeyvalue to parse the parameters.

However, when that happens, the xkeyval package can't find the string that I am passing through the pgfkeysvalue.

I am using `todonotes` to show what is going on, to simplify the problem. But, I am using other package that is rather complicated. But the error is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfkeys}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand{\foo}[3][]{\missingfigure[#1]{#2, #3}}
\newcommand{\bas}[3][]{mand: #2, #3\\}

\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,
  section/.code = {\section{#1}},
  type/.initial = bas,
  options/.initial=,
  question/.code 2 args = {\csname \pgfkeysvalueof{/test/type}\endcsname[\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/options}]{#1}{#2}},
  style/.estyle={#1}
}


\def\allrecords{%
section=first,
{
  type = foo,
  question={key1}{my lng question},
},
{
  type = foo,
  options = {figwidth=8cm},% error happens here
  question={key1}{my lng question},
},
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \allrecords {\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,style/.expanded=\x}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key value parser sees `\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/options}` as option list. Since there is no equal sign or comma, it is interpreted as key only.
The example is fixed by expanding the option list first, see the `\expandafter` in the example which expands `` \romannumeral-`\x ``, which then triggers the expansion of `\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/options}` until `\romannumeral` sees an unexpandable token or a space (which is gobbled). This way, the exact number of `\expandafter` does not need to be known.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfkeys}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand{\foo}[3][]{\missingfigure[#1]{#2, #3}}
\newcommand{\bas}[3][]{mand: #2, #3\\}

\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,
  section/.code = {\section{#1}},
  type/.initial = bas,
  options/.initial=,
  question/.code 2 args = {%
    \csname\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/type}\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter[\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral-`\x\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/options}%
    }]{#1}{#2}},
  style/.estyle={#1}
}


\def\allrecords{%
section=first,
{
  type = foo,
  question={key1}{my lng question},
},
{
  type = foo,
  options = {figwidth=8cm},% error happens here
  question={key1}{my lng question},
},
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
\foreach \x in \allrecords {\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,style/.expanded=\x}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]